# Hover image in CSS not working

Tags: html, css

On http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/index.html on the navbar there is a little gray indicator icon underneath "PLAYERS" when I hover the (class) sub-menu area and it will not display the white indicator icon. http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/img/indicator-hover.png is an image showing two icons in one image (you cannot see the white icon there).

CSS

```
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 3px;
  background: url(../img/indicator-hover.png) 0 0;
  content: '';
}
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:hover {
  background: url(../img/indicator-hover.png) 0 -10px;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse_ collapse">
    <ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="poker-players.html">PLAYERS</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="poker-players.html">EDPS PLAYERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="poker-players.html#">PLAYERS OF THE MONTH</a></li>
                <li><a href="poker-players.html#">PLAYERS OF THE YEAR</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="news-events.html">NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="founders.html">FOUNDERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:after:hover` instead of `.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your

```
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:hover
```

Should be changed to

```
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu:hover:after
```

to fix this issue

Comment: I see the li.sub-menu gets an added class on hover: "sfHover".
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li.sub-menu.sfHover:after should work